# PHP And PDO preventing Javascript injection

Tags: php, javascript, pdo, code-injection

I have a site written in PHP utilizing PDO. I am using the bindParam() function to bind to a sql insert query:

```
("insert into Table (id, date, data) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")
```

but I am able to insert a string containing

```
"<script>window.location="google.com"</script>"
```

How to prevent this?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDO is not going to stop you do that. You will need to yourself take care of the string:

1. If you do not want `<script>` tags at all, use [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/strip_tags)
2. If you want those tags but don't want them to execute, then use [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/htmlentities)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean

```
<script>window.location="google.com"</script>
```

You should worry about injection protection on row display, as you don't want to fill up the database with HTML entities.

Use `htmlspecialchars()`[1] on pages that display what's on the database.

[1] http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: What do you mean? Shouldn't I prevent these from going into the DB in the first place?

Comment: Well you can either filter on input to DB or filter on output to browser, just make sure you don't filter twice. My preference at the moment is to filter on output so as not to have the DB littered with HTML entities.